# Длина (в байтах) поля данных ping

Tags: ping

Увеличение максимального значения  длины (в байтах)  поля данных в отправленных сообщениях с эхо-запросом (в командной строке).

Максимальное значение длины (в байтах) поля данных в отправленных сообщениях с эхо-запросом - 65527 байт . А  возможно ли  увеличить это значение. (Я конечно может неконкретно  поставил вопрос, но попробуйте его понять. Я просто мало работал с командной строкой мне всего 14.) Пример:

```
ping -t -4 -l 65527 -w 1 site.ru
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вопрос не совсем относящийся к программированию.

Тем не менее, дело не в командной строке. Дело в том, что максимально IP-пакет версии 4 (что у вас установлено опцией `-4`) может содержать 65535 байт. Т.е. реально вы можете установить около 65500 байт с опцией `-l` (остальные несколько байт занимает заголовок).